# Why pushing water into a narrow channel is more difficult than pushing a narrow needle into water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, surface-tension

Assuming a hole (channel) and and an extrusion are made of **same material and have the same diameter**, why pushing water into a narrow channel is more difficult than pushing a rod (extrusion) into water?

Assuming vacuum environment (no air trapped inside the channel), since the surface tension is the same and the contact area is the same I would expect the required pressure to be the same as well.

Comment: After a short distance, the "shape" of the channel will be very different than the point of a needle.  In a 2D cross-section, it would look like a an umbrella formed in front of the channel, called a bow wave.  The combination of the creation of this bow wave and effective increase in the cross-sectional area of your object act to increase your effective drag term.  The needle only displaces the water equivalent of its volume but an open channel is a blunt object (the needle will have a bow wave too, but a much smaller cross-section).

Answer (score 2):

Pushing water through a narrow channel, the water movement all happens in close proximity to, and relative to, the channel surface.   You get viscous drag that creates a backpressure against whatever pumps the liquid.

Pushing a needle into free water, however, a layer of adjacent water may freely move with the needle, thus the needle surface need NOT have significantly different velocity than the surrounding liquid.  Because the velocity difference between the moving needle and the adjacent liquid is no longer high, the viscous (retarding) force is much less.

The inertia of a moving needle will be different, because it is dragging some
water along with it, so this can be checked experimentally.

Answer (score 0):

pushing water is difficult because in narrow pathway the water molecules will exert more force on the wall of narrow tube so due to this the liquid friction "Viscosity" will be more at the surface then at inside but on the other side
a needel have very less pointing area which have minimum contact with water molecules so the force applied will be minimum and hence the needel will easily
get into the water

> viscosity is the reason